# MySQL regex matching at least 2 dots

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

Consider the following regex

```
@(.*\..*){2,}
```

Expected behaviour:

```
a@b doesnt match
a@b.c doesnt match
a@b.c.d matches
a@b.c.d.e matches
and so on
```

Testing in regexpal it works as expected.

Using it it in a mysql select doesn't work as expected. Query:

```
SELECT * FROM `users` where mail regexp '@(.*\..*){2,}'
```

is returning lines like

```
foo@example.com
```

that should not match the given regex. Why?

Comment: It seems the problem is that you consume the whole string with the second `.*`. Use `'@([^.]*[.]){2,}'`.

Comment: That regex would allow adjacent dot characters. Did you even want that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use:

```
SELECT * FROM `users` where mail REGEXP '([^.]*\\.){2}'
```

to enforce at least 2 dots in `mail` column.

Answer (score 5):

I think the answer to your question is here.

> Because MySQL uses the C escape syntax in strings (for example, “\n”
>   to represent the newline character), you must double any “\” that you
>   use in your REGEXP strings.

[MYSQL Reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html)

Because your middle dot wasn't properly escaped it was treated as just another wildcard and in the end your expression was effectively collapsed to `@.{2,}` or `@..+`

@anubhava's answer is probably a better substitute for what you tried to do though I would note @dasblinkenlight's comment about using the character class `[.]` which will make it easy to drop in a regex you've already tested in at RegexPal.

Answer (score 2):

I would match two dots in MySQL using `like`:

```
where col like '%@.%.%'
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that `.*` (match-everything dot) matches dot '.' character. Replacing it with `[^.]*` fixes the problem:

```
SELECT *
FROM `users`
where mail regexp '@([^.]*[.]){2,}'
```

Note the use of `[.]` in place of the equivalent `\.`. This syntax makes it easier to embed the regex into programming languages that use backslash as escape character in their string literals.

[Demo.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/748d2/3)